# C Hello world: Code Blocks IDE, MinGW C compiler on windows

Tags: c, windows, gcc, mingw, codeblocks

I can't get Code Blocks IDE to compile the hello world C program it creates when you create a new C project. I've installed MinGW and it was recognised by the IDE. But when I try to build I get the following output:

```
-------------- Build: Debug in TestC3 (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler)---------------

mingw32-gcc.exe -Wall -g  -c
C:\Users\jody\codeblocks\testc3\TestC3\main.c -o obj\Debug\main.o
mingw32-g++.exe  -o bin\Debug\TestC3.exe obj\Debug\main.o    Execution
of 'mingw32-g++.exe  -o bin\Debug\TestC3.exe obj\Debug\main.o' in
'C:\Users\jody\codeblocks\testc3\TestC3' failed.
```

Why is it trying to run `mingw32-g++.exe` as well as `mingw32-gcc.exe`? (And if it shouldn't be doing this, how can I configure it not to?)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The `mingw32-gcc.exe` step is the compile step. The `mingw32-g++.exe` is the link step. This
is the correct sequence and will work if your `mingw32` installation is "normal" and correct - where "normal" means
you have installed the C++ as well as the C tools.

The link step is failing for you because `mingw32-g++.exe` cannot be executed, most likely because
it does not exist on your `PATH`. Try running `mingw32-g++.exe` at the command prompt to check.
Look in the directory where `mingw32-gcc.exe` resides to see if `mingw32-g++.exe` is also there.

If your mingw32 installation has got broken somehow I suggest you uninstall and reinstall.

If you have *intentionally* installed only the C tools then that will explain what you are
seeing, and it is easily fixed:

Both `mingw32-gcc.exe` and `mingw32-g++.exe` are just tool driver programs. When invoked
with compilation options for `.c` files, `mingw32-gcc.exe` invokes the C compiler. When invoked
with compilation options for `.cpp|cxx|...` files, `mingw32-g++.exe` invokes the C++ compiler. If
either of them is invoked with linkage options then it invokes the linker.

Codeblocks by default configures `mingw32-g++.exe` to invoke the linker because it will do equally
well for C projects, C++ projects and C/C++ projects, and it assumes you have the full C/C++ toolchain.

If you have not installed C++ tools and only want to build C, then you can use `mingw32-gcc.exe`
to invoke both the C compiler and the linker. To configure this in the CodeBlocks IDE:

- Navigate **Settings** -> **Compiler**
- Ensure that the **Selected Compiler** is `GNU GCC`
- Tab to **Toolchain executables**
- Change **Linker for dynamic libs** from `mingw32-g++.exe` to `mingw32-gcc.exe`
- OK out of **Settings** and rebuild your project.

Comment: I don't seem to be able to find any mingw32-gcc.exe file done a full search on c drive but nothings come up for it

Answer (score 3):

Firstly uninstall the codeblocks if you can't get something right. Move to codeblocks official site to download its minw.exe version so that you have a proper compiler for all of your C programs.
After installing go to `Setting>Compiler>GNU GCC compiler`.
Move to `Toolchain Executables>`.
Now set Compilers Installation Directory. Most probably it's `C:\Program Files\CodeBlocks\MinGW\bin`. Now you have to select and locate your C compiler as it is in the above mentioned directory.
After that rebulid and run your program.

Answer (score 0):

It may occur because compiler installation directory path is wrong.to fix it
settings -> compiler -> toolchain executables. now set compiler directory to compiler folder. it must be in CodeBlocks folder if you downloaded CodeBlocks compiler integrated version(ex: C:\Program Files\CodeBlocks\MinGW). else you need browse to location where compiler is installed

if you can't find compiler then uninstall codeblocks and download again . but this time make sure you downloaded one which has "mingw" in name for windows.